# Symfony 3.4 error while retrieving session data

Tags: php, session, symfony-3.4

I'm able to set and get session data within the same controller like below :

```
$this->session->set('userid', $dbres [0]['user_id']);
$user_id = $this->get('session')->get('userid');
```

This works fine.

But If I use

```
$user_id = $this->get('session')->get('userid');
```

What mistake have I made here?

In another controller this error is thrown : 
          Call to a member function get() on null

**Edit**:

```
Please help me, I have the following classes 
class AssociationController extends FOSRestController {
            public $session;
            public function __construct(){
                /*** Set Session ***/
                $this->session = new Session();
            }

            /**
             * @Rest\Post("/session/get")
             */
            public function postTestSetSessionAction(Request $request) {
                    $this->session->set('userid', $dbres [0]['user_id']);
                    $Obj = new ComplaintsController();
                    $Obj->getSessionData();
            }

    }

class ComplaintsController extends FOSRestController {
            public function getSessionData() {
                $user_id = $this->get('session')->get('userid');
            }
    }
```

When I call  http://localhost/app_dev.php/session/get, I am getting the error "Call to a member function get() on null"

Comment: Sounds like there are differences in the controllers then?

Comment: @JonStirling there are two controllers : in controller1 "AssociationController" I am setting the session variable. And trying to get it's value in another controller "ComplaintsController" through a function in "AssociationController".

Answer (score 0):

Which controller does your Controllers extends?

Try to get the session from the container:

`$this->container->get('session')->get('userid');`

Comment: Did you try to get the session from the container as I've shown?